# d3 changes time zone while parsing

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js

I have date time as "2015-05-04 01:59:36". I am parsing these dates as follows-

```
var d= "2015-05-04 01:59:36";
var input_date_format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
```

On parsing the date like this-

```
input_date_format.parse(d);
```

I get this date object-

```
2015-05-03T23:59:36.000Z
```

The date is getting offset by -2 hours. The system clock is at a timezone of +02:00. How to prevent this from happenig? Also if I run this d3 code on another system with different time zone, would it offset accordingly? I want the date to be preserved as it is while parsing.

How can it be done?
Thanks

Comment: [This post](http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/9671241) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution would probably be to append "-0000" to all your timestamps, and then add "%Z" to the end of your format string. This way, you are explicitly telling D3 to use UTC for your timestamp.

So like this:

```js
var d= "2015-05-04 01:59:36";
d += " -0000";
var input_date_format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z");
```

More info on D3 time formatting in [their official docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting).